# Make CASE-WHEN-clause emit a tuple

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
       m1.ID, 
       (CASE WHEN <condition> THEN
             <expr1.1>
        ELSE
             <expr1.2>
        END) as [Tag1], 
       (CASE WHEN <condition> THEN
             <expr2.1>
        ELSE
             <expr2.2>
        END) as [Tag2], 
       (CASE WHEN <condition> THEN
             <expr3.1>
        ELSE
             <expr3.2>
        END) as [Tag3],
  FROM MyTable AS m1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN MyOtherTable m2
            ON m2.ID = m1.ID
```

As you can see, I have the same condition three times, but different expressions in each branch. Is it possible in SQL to only write the condition once and let it emit a three-tuple in this case? Or is it in any other way possible to prevent writing the same condition multiple times?

I want to use this in Sqlite3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly (afaik) SQLite does not have common table expressions, but you could calculate the expression in a subquery and use CASE on that instead.

It will not eliminate any case expression, but it can simplify the expression in each and it will only need to be changed in once place;

As an example, the query;

```
SELECT CASE WHEN sel=1 OR sel=3 AND a<>2 OR sel=2 AND a<>3 OR sel=4 THEN a ELSE b END e,
       CASE WHEN sel=1 OR sel=3 AND a<>2 OR sel=2 AND a<>3 OR sel=4 THEN b ELSE c END f,
       CASE WHEN sel=1 OR sel=3 AND a<>2 OR sel=2 AND a<>3 OR sel=4 THEN c ELSE a END g
FROM olle;
```

...could be rewritten as...

```
SELECT CASE WHEN exp THEN a ELSE b END e,
       CASE WHEN exp THEN b ELSE c END f,
       CASE WHEN exp THEN c ELSE a END g
FROM (SELECT *, sel=1 OR sel=3 AND a<>2 OR sel=2 AND a<>3 OR sel=4 exp FROM olle);
```

This example may not look like it's simplified much, but for a complex expression or one that is changed often it may make quite a lot of difference.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/41332/5).

Comment: SQLite recently added common table expressions, see http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Very cool :) Neither SQLite implementation at SQLFiddle seems to have them yet though :-/

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo The common table expressions are only in since 3.8.3. The GUIs I'm using (or rather forced to use) on Windows do not yet support this version of SQLite, so CTS are out of scope for me - sadly. But good hint anyways!

Answer (score 0):

That's basically it.

You can use a `CASE` statement in a `JOIN` to a table, that would allow you to get down to one `CASE` statement, but unless your data is already structured in a way that makes this possible it's probably not worthwhile.